# Is precise video frame positioning possible with the HTML video element?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I would like to use a web interface to select time points in a video for making frame-precise cuts, passing the time values obtained by having the user scrub through the video along to **ffmpeg** or some other tool.

I've already seen a [warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) that gives me pause about whether this will be possible:

> Reduced time precision
>
> To offer protection against timing attacks and fingerprinting, browsers may round or otherwise adjust the value returned by `currentTime`.

While testing this concept using Chrome I seem to be getting `currentTime` values with millisecond precision. Perhaps that precision is illusory, and the time values I'm seeing have some random noise deliberately added to them?

What seems odd to me is that I would have expected (or at least hoped) that there was a clear relationship between the time values reported by a video element as a user plays, pauses, and scrubs their way through a video, and the video's frame rate. That doesn't seem to be the case.

Using a sample video with a 23.976 frame rate, I was hoping to see a time values that were very close, within a small amount of round-off error, to multiples of 1 / 23.976 seconds. That's not what I'm getting. I'm seeing time values with no consistent relation to the frame rate of the video. I even created a video-only sample with no audio track, just in case the timing I was seeing was based on audio, and that made no difference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video Test</title>
</head>
<script>
  const fr = 23.976;
  let video;
  let lastTime = -1;

  function init() {
    video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
      const ct = video.currentTime;

      if (lastTime !== -1) {
        const delta = ct - lastTime;

        console.log(ct, ct * fr, delta, delta * fr);
      }
      else
        console.log(ct, ct * fr);

      lastTime = ct;
    });
  }
</script>
<body onload="init()">

<video id="video" controls width="1080">
  <source src="sample-video-only.mkv"/>
</video>
<br><br>
<button onclick="video.currentTime -= 1 / 23.976">Frame -</button>
<button onclick="video.currentTime += 1 / 23.976">Frame +</button><br><br>
<button onclick="video.currentTime -= 10 / 23.976">Frame -10</button>
<button onclick="video.currentTime += 10 / 23.976">Frame +10</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Output while playing the sample video:

```
0.291765 6.99535764
0.554231 13.288242456 0.26246600000000003 6.292884816000001
0.830544 19.913122943999998 0.2763129999999999 6.624880487999998
1.095199 26.258491224 0.2646550000000001 6.3453682800000015
1.352909 32.437346184 0.2577099999999999 6.178854959999997
1.620717 38.858310792 0.26780800000000005 6.420964608000001
1.885501 45.206771976 0.26478400000000013 6.348461184000003
2.150835 51.56841995999999 0.26533399999999974 6.361647983999993
2.420251 58.027937976 0.2694160000000001 6.459518016000002
2.68662 64.41440112 0.2663690000000001 6.386463144000001
2.948961 70.704288936 0.26234100000000016 6.289887816000004
3.211832 77.00688403199999 0.26287099999999963 6.302595095999991
3.486875 83.601315 0.27504300000000015 6.594430968000004
3.752217 89.963154792 0.26534199999999997 6.361839791999999
4.016692 96.304207392 0.264475 6.3410526
```

Am I stuck with having to create a native (Windows/macOS/Linux) app if I want frame-precise timing, or can I trick the HTML `video` element into doing what I need, at least perhaps with some web browsers?